# findReleaseById with promise - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise

I have a function which find a Release by id which returns a promise.
But in the second then release is not defined. I don't understand why.
Could someone explain and suggest a code edit. I'm really stuck on this.

My Code

```
var findReleaseById = function(id) {
  return Release.find({ _id: id }).select('releasedate').exec()
    .then(releaseArray => Array.isArray(releaseArray) ? releaseArray[0] : undefined)
    .then(release ? release.releasedate : undefined)
}
```

Gives me

```
ReferenceError: release is not defined
```

**[EDIT 1]**

The above function is inside a bigger function. this function calculates a difference between 2 releases

```
exports.release_difference = (req, resp, next) => {
  const relid1 = req.query.rel1;
  const relid2 = req.query.rel2;

  var findFeatures = function(releases) {
    const promises = releases.map(release =>
      Feature.find({
        'release._id': release._id
      }).select('name description release').exec()
    )

    return Promise.all(promises)
      .then(featureArrayArray => featureArrayArray.filter(featureArray => Array.isArray(featureArray)))
      .then(featureArrayArray => [].concat(featureArrayArray))
      .catch(error => {});

  }

  var findChanges = function(releases) {
    const promises = releases.map(release =>
      Change.find({
        'release._id': release._id
      }).select('name description relatedFeature release').exec()
    )

    return Promise.all(promises)
      .then(changeArrayArray => changeArrayArray.fill(changeArray => Array.isArray(changeArray)))
      .then(changeArrayArray => [].concat(changeArrayArray))
      .catch(error => {});
  }

  var makepdf = function(features, changes, releasess, template, options, cb) {
    pdfcreator.makepdf(features, changes, releasess, template, options, function(res) {
      cb(res.filename);
    });
  }

  var findReleaseById = function(id) {
    return Release.find({
        _id: id
      }).select('releasedate').exec()
      .then(releaseArray => Array.isArray(releaseArray) ? releaseArray[0] : undefined)
      .then(release => release ? release.releasedate : undefined)
  }

  const releasedate1Promise = findReleaseById(relid1);
  const releasedate2Promise = findReleaseById(relid2);

  Promise.all(releasedate1Promise, releasedate2Promise)
    .then(([releasedate1, releasedate2]) => {
      return Release.find({
        'releasedate': {
          '$gt': releasedate1,
          '$lte': releasedate2
        }
      }).sort('version').exec()
    })
    .then(releasesBetween => {
      const fsPromise = findFeatures(releasesBetween);
      const csPromise = findChanges(releasesBetween);

      return Promise.all(fsPromise, csPromise)
    })
    .then(([fs, cs]) => {
      makepdf(fs, cs, releasesBetween, template, options, function(file) {
        resp.download(file);
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `catch` block as one or more requests throws an error. Also, use mongoose `lean` function (`.lean().exec()`) so the response is a plain javascript object and not a mongoose document.

Comment: TypeError: (var)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function
    at Function.all (native)
    at exports.release_difference (/home/larssuffys/bigdisk/git-repositories/retrakt.git/node-server/controllers/releases.js:175:9)

releases.js line 175 is Promise.all(releasedate1Promise,releasedate2Promise).then(...)

Comment: I think Promise.all should have an array (or other iterator) as argument. Try `Promise.all([releasedate1Promise,releasedate2Promise])` instead

Comment: @NicoVanBelle Yes indeed it requires an array. in the mean time i found that mistake myself. 

Now i get this:

{ CastError: Cast to date failed for value "[ 2018-06-08T00:00:00.000Z, 2018-06-10T00:00:00.000Z ]" at path "releasedate" for model "Release"

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
.then(release?release.releasedate:undefined)
```

`release` is `undefined`. You need to receive it as a parameter in the function:

```
.then(release => release ? release.releasedate : undefined)
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast repy. But now i get

(node:5108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: (var)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

Comment: const relid1 = req.query.rel1;
const releasedate1Promise = findReleaseById(relid1);